# Wrong result for mesh generation when using integers for mesh size

Tags: bugs, finite-element-method

Can somebody explain me why this happens?

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`


L = 10;
r = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];

mesh = ToElementMesh[ r ];

mesh2 = ToElementMesh[ 
   ImplicitRegion[
    Abs[x] < L && Abs[y] < L && x^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, y}]];
GraphicsRow[{mesh2["Wireframe"], mesh["Wireframe"]}]

L = 10.;
r = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];

mesh = ToElementMesh[ r ];

mesh2 = ToElementMesh[ 
   ImplicitRegion[
    Abs[x] < L && Abs[y] < L && x^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, y}]];
GraphicsRow[{mesh2["Wireframe"], mesh["Wireframe"]}]
```

[image]

The only difference is that in one case L is an integer and on the other not. The error happens when `L<10` but not as bad as in the example. If the radius of the disk in the implicit region is set to `1.` the problem disappears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** This is fixed in version 11.0:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
L = 10;
r = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
ToElementMesh[r]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

**Old message:**

That's a bug and I have reported it. You have one workaround in your question and here is another one:

```
ToElementMesh[
  ImplicitRegion[-L < x <= L && -L <= y <= L && x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {x, 
    y}]];
```

What happens is that the default mesh generator for 2D gets into trouble with the `Abs` and then the mesh generation falls back to `RegionPlot`. That however can not deal with holes well, as can be seen.

Another workaround is to specify a larger region bound to `ToElementMesh`:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
L = 10;
r = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-L, -L}, {L, L}], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]];
mesh2 = ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[
    Abs[x] < L && Abs[y] < L && x^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, y}], {{-L - 1/10, 
     L + 1/10}, {-L - 1/10, L + 1/10}}];
mesh2["Wireframe"]
```